# Finding the depth when T(1) = 0 for a recursion tree

Tags: algorithm, tree, recurrence

so I was trying to solve recurrences using the recursion tree method, and I came across this this issue.

For a relation given like this:

`T(n) = n + 3T(n/2) ; T(1) = 1`,

the height of the tree will be `log2(n)`. But when the base condition changes to `T(1) = 0`, how can we find the height of the tree?

This is the method I use to find the height of the tree,

At a depth let's say `h`, for the above recurrence relation with T(1) = 1, the stop condition will be:

`n/2^h = 1` => `n = 2^h` => `log2(n) = h`

But when T(1) = 0, the process becomes,

`n/2^h = 0` => `n = 0` => `????` (height term is eliminated)

Can someone guide me through getting the height of the tree when the base condition is T(1) = 0?

Comment: The height of the tree does not depend on T(1).

Comment: Umm, that is the stopping condition, so it kind of does?

Comment: No. There are two 1s in T(1)=1. You are confusing them.